# vs2015 ionic cordova no icons in ios simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, taco

I have created a ionic cordova app in vs2015. The project has ionic created images for icon and splash.  These work fine on android. When i build and run the app on ios the icon and splash remain the cordova default. In the platforms/ios directory the corrct images are in the images.xcassets folder.  But are not being picked up by the app in the simulator.

Any one come across this issue. I have tried deleting and rebuilding, clearing cache etc.  config.xml code below:

```html
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
  <preference name="KeepRunning" value="True" />
  <preference name="ShowTitle" value="True" />
  <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="True" />
  <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="True" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
  </feature>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" version="1.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" version="1.1.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" version="2.1.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.2.1" />
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" version="1.0.8" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" version="2.11.1" src="https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro.git" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-extension" version="1.2.9" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" version="1.2.0" />
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi" />
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi" />
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi" />
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi" />
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi" />
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi" />
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87" />
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136" />
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334" />
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242" />
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536" />
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768" />
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024" />
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960" />
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480" />
  </platform>
  <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" version="3.2.1-dev" src="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git" />
  <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I deploy to a remote device from VS2015 to a mac.
Icons and splashcreens are the defaults ones.

But when :

- I copy and paste the  "platforms/ios" folder from windows to the Mac
- and I build the project on the mac with Xcode to the connected device

-> icons and splashscreen are the good ones and are well displayed on the deployed device.

And also when the app is testable from tesflight or published, icons and splashscreen are corrects.

Answer (score 0):

just found the answer here:

[Cordova ios icon (and splashscreen) not showing with Ionic resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36742560/cordova-ios-icon-and-splashscreen-not-showing-with-ionic-resources)

```
<splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
```

slashs should be

```
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
```